# How to do arithmetic operations on data fields and aggregate functions in where clause?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

I'm using this query to return the distribution of a float field around its average:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS [Count], Result FROM    (
  SELECT ROUND(Result - AVG(Result) OVER(), 1) Result FROM Results)
GROUP  BY Result
```

This query returns the distance between all records and the mean. Now, I need to filter the records which are out of the ±3SD range. I thought perhaps I could easily achieve this by changing my query to this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS [Count], Result FROM    (
  SELECT ROUND(Result - AVG(Result) OVER(), 1) Result FROM Results 
    HAVING Abs(Result - AVG(Result)) OVER() < 3 * STDEV(Result) OVER())
GROUP  BY Result
```

But SQL Server is giving me two errors:

> Column 'Results.Result' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

How can I achieve what I'm looking for? Google isn't kind to me today :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the second error message indicated, windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses - so rather than including them in the HAVING clause, include them in the inner SELECT and then select on them in the outer WHERE clause - like so:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS [Count], Result FROM    
(SELECT ROUND(Result - AVG(Result) OVER(), 1) Result,
        Abs(Result - AVG(Result) OVER()) avgdiff,
        STDEV(Result) OVER() stddev
 FROM Results) r
WHERE avgdiff < 3 * stddev
GROUP  BY Result
```